# Why Eclipse and Visual Studio read Python string in a different way?

Tags: python, eclipse, visual-studio

I always use Eclipse on my Mac for Python coding. Today, I did Python coding in Visual Studio on Windows. When I re-run the code on the Eclipse of my Mac, something weird happened and I don't know why.

I'm using **Python 2.7** on both Eclipse and Visual Studio. The data input and the code are the same too. The data input is in .txt format

This is a sample line of data:

```
<p>abcbdABCDE</p>pewpewpew
```

In Visual Studio, it could recognize there is a `\n` after `pewpewpew`, but Eclipse could not.

So, when I was using `endswith()` method, if I type `endswith("</p>pewpewpew\n")`, Visual Studio could help find the whole line of data, but Eclipse cannot, even when I tried `endswith("</p>pewpewpew")`, it still cannot recognize the whole line.

I'm wondering whether this is because of some settings in Eclipse or Mac will change the .txt format when I just downloaded the data I used on Windows?

**Note:** In the real problem, I have to use `endswith()`, cannot use `in` or `not in`

**Simplified Code Sample (it works on Visual Studio not on Eclipse)**

```
pth = "[file path]"
f = open(pth)

for l in f:
    if l.endswith("</p>pewpewpew\n"):
        print l
```

Comment: Can you crate a minimal code example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with Eclipse or Visual Studio, and everything to do with how newlines are treated differently on your two platforms. Are you sure that the two files are identical, byte for byte?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the data input file is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the issue here is how Windows and Unix-like systems actually record newline characters.  In Unix-like Environments, a single character is used "\n" - the line feed character.  In Windows Environments, two characters are used to denote a new line - "\r\n" - the carriage return and the line feed character.

If the file you are parsing was written in Windows, then the line ends with "\r\n".  This is my best guess.  VisualStudio is probably configured to treat "\n" and "\r\n" in a similar way.  Whereas Eclipse requires you to explicitly state that the line ends in "\r\n".

The best way to determine how the file is actually written is to open it in a text editor that will provide a visual interpretation of non-displayable ASCII characters.  I generally do this with Notepad++ and turn on the "Show All Characters" option.